# Lower priority task with getchar() halts higher task in FreeRTOS - how to fix that?

Tags: freertos

I have two functions:

**shell()** uses getchar() to get user input

**playLED()** plays a LED animation

I have two tasks running in FreeRTOS

```
    xTaskCreate(
                    shell,
                    "shell",
                    512,
                    NULL,
                    1,
                    NULL);

    xTaskCreate(
                    playLED,
                    "playLED",
                    512,
                    NULL,
                    15,
                    NULL );
    vTaskStartScheduler();
```

Then I noticed the LED animation play become step-wise, it changes only when getchar() received input from user, instead of a smooth animation.

I've already set LED priority a lot higher, however this didn't fix the halt. Is there anything else that I should configure somewhere?

The code is run on NXP LPC54018 board with MCUXpresso. A similar problem on a different device can be found at https://os.mbed.com/questions/781/Skip-getchar-if-no-input-using-interrupt/

Comment: Can you better describe your environment (CPU, libraries, µC, toolset)? `getchar()` is not part of FreeRTOS. So only answers specific to your environment can be given.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using it with a MCUxpresso on NXP LPC 54018

Answer (score 1):

Does getchar() disable interrupts at all when receiving input? In that case the FreeRTOS scheduler will not be able to run the high priority task.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's what I suspect but I don't know how to fix that. My expectation that the interrupt should be isolated to this task only but somehow it affect everything

Answer (score 0):

I think vTaskDelay(1) in the beginning of the task with getChar will resolve the problem.

Also you can change order of creation of tasks, it can also help.